# PLSQL-Parametric definition of group function

Tags: plsql, timestamp

I have a table where i want to apply some aggregation functions having as criteria the grouping of spesific element of specific column. Assume the example below:

```
TIMESTAMP   SITE    VALUE

10:00            A  100
10:00            B  50
10:00            C  25
10:00            D  25
10:05            A  25
10:05            B  15
10:05            C  5
10:05            D  10
```

i want to find the average value grouping by `SITE`, `TIMESTAMP` but the site A,B i want it to be estimated as one, meaning that i wanted to `REPLACE B WITH A` have AND THEN find the average:

```
TIMESTAMP   SITE    VALUE
10:00            A  75
10:00            A  75
10:00            C  25
10:00            D  25
10:05            A  20
10:05            A  20
10:05            C  5
10:05            D  10
```

One way is to update the table setting `B=A`, but this is not such a sophisticated solution if i want in future to group more `SITES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to update the table.

```
SELECT CASE site WHEN 'B' THEN 'A' ELSE site END as site
      ,timestamp
      ,AVG(value)
FROM sites
GROUP BY CASE site WHEN 'B' THEN 'A' ELSE site END
        ,timestamp
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the averages of uncombined and combined sites separately and then union them togeather, like this -

```
SELECT timestamp, site, AVG(value) FROM
(
    -- uncombined
    SELECT timestamp, site, value FROM TABLE WHERE site NOT IN ('A', 'B')

    UNION ALL

    -- combined A, B
    SELECT timestamp, 'AB' site, AVG(value) val
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY timestamp
    WHERE site IN ('A', 'B') 
) U
GROUP BY timestamp, site
```

Just an idea, not tested the sql